# Firebase Auth getProfilePhoto() returns local path

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, picasso

I'm using Firebase Auth to manage a user's profile.
The users are able to set avatar for their account using firebase auth's stock profile builder.

My code for setting avatar is

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case CODE_PICK:
        {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                if(data != null)
                {
                    loadingDialog.ShowLoadingDialog();
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setPhotoUri(uri)
                                .build();

                    if(user != null)
                    {
                        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<Void> task)
                                    {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            Target target = new PicassoImageTarget().picassoImageTarget(AccountActivity.this, "media", "avatar.png");

                                            Picasso.get()
                                                    .load(uri)
                                                    .into(target);

                                            userVars.setAvatar(true);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, "Failed to upload avatar! Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                        loadingDialog.HideLoadingDialog();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
}
```

My code for retrieving the photo when a user logs in is

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null)
{
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

    Log.e("SSA", String.valueOf(photoUrl));

    Target target = new PicassoImageTarget().picassoImageTarget(SplashScreenActivity.this, "media", "avatar.png");
    if(photoUrl != null)
    {
        Picasso.get()
               .load(photoUrl)
               .into(target);

        userVars.setAvatar(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Picasso.get()
               .load(R.drawable.ic_main_avatar)
               .into(target);

        userVars.setAvatar(false);
    }
}
```

When I log the photoUrl returned after the `Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();` it returns the local path (`E/SSA: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/imagename.jpg`) instead of the remote link.
Hence my avatar isn't loaded when opening the same account from a different device or in the same device after clearing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Authentication doesn't do any processing on the photo URL you provide. So when you call `.setPhotoUri(uri)`, that `uri` is a local image and that is literally the value it stores.

If you want a URL that others can also access, you'll first need to upload the image somewhere, get the URL to the image in that location, and then pass *that* URL to `setPhotoUri()`.

A common place to store these images is in Cloud Storage for Firebase, although that is in no way required. If you'd like to do that, check out its documentation on [uploading an image](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_files) and then [getting a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url) (which is a publicly readable, read-only URL that you probably want to use for the profile picture).

Comment: Didn't expect a reply from @Frank himself but thank you very much. 
For the record, my initial method was actually using Firebase Storage. But later when I found that Firebase Auth had a native profile photo method, I discarded it as to avoid an additional implementation when I could achieve the same with Auth alone.